# Find my iPhone: how to identify each device?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone

A friend of mine got her iPhone stolen. When entering iCloud to activate the "Find my iPhone" feature, I see that her account has 3 phones associated with it. The 3 phones are named:

- Iphone
- Iphone
- (Name)'s Iphone.

How can I know which is her current one? Her previous models are a iPhone 4S, an iPhone 5 and an iPhone 6. I don't see any place to check each phone's model.

Comment: Where are the other two now? I've they're just gathering dust in a drawer somewhere, then put all three in lost mode.

Comment: It's six years later, and this glaring defect is still not fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you load the image of your device in "Find My iPhone" in a new tab, you are able to get the model identifier ID from the URL. As an example, here's the URL for an iPad that I lost quite a while ago:

```
https://statici.icloud.com/fmipmobile/deviceImages-9.0/iPad/iPad2,1/locked-nolocation_ipad.png
```

I wasn't sure whether this was an iPad 1 or 2, but the URL clearly shows that it's an iPad 2 (`iPad2,1`).

See [this list](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_capability/mac-specs-by-machine-model-machine-id.html) of all Mac model identifiers, and [this one](http://www.everyi.com/by-identifier/ipod-iphone-ipad-specs-by-model-identifier.html) for mobile devices.

Comment: This is a clever workaround to a problem that should never have existed. It also isn't applicable to the Find My application, which also has no way to reveal device model or any other information that would help you distinguish between them.

Answer (score 1):

It's too late now to identify the iPhone.  This must be done **prior** to losing the device, when you're able to provide a name for it.  Find iPhone doesn't list the specific device.

To name the device, go to `Settings -> General -> About` and in the **Name** field enter a specific device name (for example, 'PaulJ's iPhone 5s').  Then, when you need to locate the device, it will get the name you entered and it can be identified.

The only thing you can do now is the process of elimination.  Figure out which of the 3 devices listed is not accounted for someplace or, perhaps, not turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity I logged into my account to see if there was any way of differentiating.

Other than the iPad and the Mac mini, they are remarkably difficult to tell apart. This is further compounded by the name issue. That said, in the below image, the top iPhone is a 7, the next one is a 5, the next one is a 5s, the next one is a 6, the one after that is a 5s, then a 5, and the one at the very bottom is a 6s.

Note if they say offline and you tap on them, you get a bigger image. (If they're not offline, you get only a slightly bigger image.) You can also try using your browser's zoom function. Remember that the 6 series moved the sleep/wake button to the right side, so that may help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your answers. In the end, as usual, I found the answer in the most stupid way possible: I went to the "Settings" section in iCloud.com, and in "My devices", it shows the currently backed up devices. The iPhone that shows up there is the "(name)'s iPhone" one.

(It hasn't appeared yet, though :-( ).